# Are there any general guidelines for dealing with imbalanced data through upsampling or downsampling?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-science, data-preprocessing

Are there any general guidelines for dealing with imbalanced data through upsampling/downsampling?

This [Google developer guide](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/data-prep/construct/sampling-splitting/imbalanced-data) suggests performing downsampling with upweighting, but for the most part I've found upsampling usually works better in practice ([some corroboration](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/6czlty/d_upsampling_vs_weighting_whats_the_best_way_to/)).

Is there any clear consensus or empirical study of what works in practice, or when to use which?  Does it matter which classification algorithm you use?